# VFP Multiline caption Tab

Tags: tabs, visual-foxpro

I'm working with the pageframe control in VFP 9.0 with a bunch of tabs. I'm trying to achieve multi-lines caption in each tab as in the following screen, but I don't know how to do.

I tried these, but no luck.

```
.Caption = 'Watch 1' + chr(13)+chr(10) + '(00~04)'  
.Caption = 'Watch 1' + chr(13)+ '(00~04)'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without some fancy advanced smoke-and-mirrors going on, VFP does not do multi-line tab text within pageframe controls...  And I've been using VFP since vs VFP3 back about 1993 when it was first released.

Comment: @Sithu, ok on the acceptance of answers, sometimes new users just don't understand the system early on.  As for my answer to your question, you CAN NOT do multi-line caption in tab pages.  I've never seen it done in VFP (since 1993).  The only other way is to create your own alternate interface as such.  Thus the smoke-and-mirrors.  If you want, I can describe how I might approach it, but it would be very advanced.

Comment: Yes, if you have something, please share it.